# Using aggregates on multiple tables in Linq to SQL

Tags: sql, linq, join, aggregate

I have been searching for an answer for days now, and each time I think I am close I run into some roadblocks.

I have two tables, one with `players` (playerID, Name) and one with `activities` (actionID, playerID, Quarter, Score). I want to `join` these tables and aggregate them, counting the scores for each player in each quarter. In the output I want to see content from the player table (Name) as well as from the activities table (Quarter) and of course the aggregate Sum(score).

in SQL, it would be something along these lines:

```
SELECT p.Name, a.Quarter, 'TotalScore' = sum(a.Score) 
FROM players p
JOIN activities a on p.playerID = a.playerID
GROUP BY p.Name, a.Quarter
```

I have found several examples, using either Join or Group Join, but I seem to be unable to get the data from the child table except for the aggregate.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to use `Join` (see [Why use LINQ Join on a simple one-many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229569/why-use-linq-join-on-a-simple-one-many-relationship)), but you will need to use `GroupBy`.

```
var players = context.Players;
var activities = players.SelectMany(p => p.Activities);
var groups = activities.GroupBy(a => new 
{
    Name = a.Player.Name,
    Quarter = a.Quarter
});

var result = groups.Select(g => new 
{
    Name = g.Key.Name,
    Quarter = g.key.Quarter,
    Score = g.Sum(a => a.Score)
};
```