# how to convert T-SQL Query to linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i have 4 table in SQL: `DocumentType`,`ClearanceDocument`,`Request`, `RequestDocument`.
i want when page load and user select one request, show all Document Based on `clearanceType` in `RequestTable` and check in `RequestDocument` and when `exist` set `is_exist=true`

I have written this query with `SqlServer Query Editor` for get result this Scenario but i can't convert this Query to Linq

```
    select *,
    is_Orginal=
    (select is_orginal from CLEARANCE_REQUEST_DOCUMENT 
    where 
    DOCUMENT_ID=a.DOCUMENT_ID and REQUEST_ID=3)
    from 
    DOCUMENT_TYPES a
    where 
    DOCUMENT_ID in 
    (select DOCUMENT_ID from CLEARANCE_DOCUMENTS dt 
    where 
    dt.CLEARANCE_ID=
    (SELECT R.CLEARANCE_TYPE FROM CLEARANCE_REQUEST R 
    WHERE 
    R.REQUEST_ID=3))
```

i write this Query in linq but not work

```
 var list = (from r in context.CLEARANCE_REQUEST
                        where r.REQUEST_ID == 3
                        join cd in context.CLEARANCE_DOCUMENTS on r.CLEARANCE_TYPE equals cd.CLEARANCE_ID
                        join dt in context.DOCUMENT_TYPES on cd.DOCUMENT_ID equals dt.DOCUMENT_ID into outer
                        from t in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                                   {
                                        r.REQUEST_ID,
                                        cd.CLEARANCE_ID,
                                        t.DOCUMENT_ID,
                                        t.DOCUMENT_NAME,
                                        is_set=(from b in context.CLEARANCE_REQUEST_DOCUMENT where 
                                                    b.REQUEST_ID==r.REQUEST_ID && b.DOCUMENT_ID==t.DOCUMENT_ID
                                                    select new{b.IS_ORGINAL})
                                   }

                       ).ToList();
```

I want convert this Query to `LINQ`. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: @M.B.: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting an compiler error? A runtime exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: @M.B. - Sorry, I edited the post and the later part that you posted is gone. Can you please put that again? My bad.

Comment: @  Shaks: np, i edit Question and add my linq code.

Comment: Please explain in plain English what the query should return.

Comment: @ Amiram Korach: i explain Question in post, please help me. thanks.

Comment: The SQL returns `DOCUMENT_TYPES.*` and a `BIT` for `is_original`, but your LINQ attempts to return properties from a range of objects. They are completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to manually join objects returned from an Entity Framework context.

See [Why use LINQ Join on a simple one-many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229569/why-use-linq-join-on-a-simple-one-many-relationship)

If you use the framework as intended your job will be much easier.

```
var result = var clearanceTypes = context.CLEARANCE_REQUEST
    .Single(r => r.REQUEST_ID == 3)
    .CLEARANCE_DOCUMENTS
    .SelectMany(dt => dt.DOCUMENT_TYPES)
    .Select(a => new 
    {
        DocumentType = a,
        IsOriginal = a.CLEARANCE_REQUEST_DOCUMENT.is_original
    });
```

Comment: @ Kirk Broadhurst: thanks for help me, but between Clearance_Request and Clearance_document not relationship. request just with Clearance_Request_Document have a relationship

Answer (score 1):

Since your query won't be executed untill you iterate over the data, you can split your query in several subqueries to help you obtain the results like this:

```
var clearanceIds = context.CLEARANCE_REQUEST
                          .Where(r => r.REQUEST_ID == 3)
                          .Select(r => r.CLEARANCE_TYPE);
var documentIds = context.CLEARANCE_DOCUMENTS
                         .Where(dt => clearanceIds.Contains(dt.CLEARANCE_ID))
                         .Select(dt => dt.DOCUMENT_ID);
var result = context.DOCUMENT_TYPES
                    .Where(a => documentIds.Contains(a.DOCUMENT_ID))
                    .Select(a => new
                    {
                        // Populate properties here
                        IsOriginal = context.CLEARANCE_REQUEST_DOCUMENT
                                            .Single(item => item.DOCUMENT_ID == a.DOCUMENT_ID &&
                                                              item.REQUEST_ID == 3)
                                            .IS_ORIGINAL
                    })
                    .ToList();
```