# Linq SelectMany query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query:

```
 DateTime cutoffDate = new DateTime(1997, 1, 1); 

 var orders = 
     from c in customers 
     where c.Region == "WA" 
     from o in c.Orders 
     where o.OrderDate >= cutoffDate 
     select new { c.CustomerID, o.OrderID };
```

How can this be written in Linq Lambda? 
BTW, is this known as a SelectMany query?

Also this can be done with a join, what is the pros and cons with doing it as shown above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a `SelectMany`. You use `SelectMany` to 'flatten' a nested or tiered collection (in this case, the orders are nested under customers) into a simple single-tier collection.

```
customers.Where(c => c.Region == "WA")
    .SelectMany(c => c.Orders)
    .Where(o => o.Orderdate >= cutoffDate)
    .Select(x => new { x.OrderID, x.Customer.CustomerID });
```

If the Orders are a property of the Customer then there is no need to use a join.

Comment: Broadhust -  Thank you for your response. Is there a benefit of using SelectMany vs. just a join? Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: It depends on the LINQ provider; are you using `LINQ-to-SQL` or `-Objects`?  See my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229569/146077

Comment: Normally the rule in LINQ is 'use whatever is simplest'. We don't use LINQ because it's efficient, we use it because it's easy to write and easy to read. In this case the `Join` could well be less efficient, because you're rejoining something that already has a reference, but I don't know without profiling it.