# LINQ statement getting value from one table depending on the other table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am trying to make a small website using mvc3 and c# and im a little stuck with this LINQ query.

I have two tables:

1. Agents (id, firstName, lastName, login, password)
2. SubAgents (subAgentsId, agentsId)

here the `Agents.id == SubAgents.agentsId`

```
var query = from subAgent in db.SubAgents
                        join agent in Agents on subAgent.AgentID equals agent.ID
                select agent;
```

I have a similar join statement thats running for Agent and Client. but that runs fine. here unfortunately it keeps giving me this error.

> "Entity command ExecutionException was unhandled by user code"

This error pops up just before I am ready to send the subagents details to the view.

Dont know what im doing wrong.

Comment: Can you post the inner exception?

Comment: @eranga {"Invalid object name 'dbo.AgentAgentRelationships'."}... this is the inner exception message. this 'AgentAgentRelationships' the name of the second table in my database. thanks :)

Comment: The table EF is refers to does not exist or does not have permissions to access the table.

Comment: I dont know why it was looking at the old named table. I had changed it before I started working with that table. I tried to refresh it and reload the table but dint work. so i just plainly put it back to the old name. Thanks for all your help Eranga :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the navigation property.

```
var query = from subAgent in db.SubAgents
            select subAgent.agent;
```

Comment: thank you for that kirk, i tried that... how can i call one table from another table. doesnt it need a join or something. I am pretty new to this so if my question is really silly im sorry! but i cant seem to figure this one out. thanks again! :)

Comment: Hi Sindhoor, it's a good question because it isn't always obvious. If the database objects have a foreign key, then the framework will generate properties for each related pair of items. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229569/146077

Comment: HI again, I looked at the question that you had asked before. I understand how the joins works. ive been getting ---- {"Invalid object name 'dbo.AgentAgentRelationships'."} ----- as the inner joint exceptions. and really dont know how to get around it. ive been stuck doing this for the past 2 days now :(

Comment: Are you using LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework? Try updating your classes from the database. If LINQ-to-SQL, remove and re-add the tables to the designer. If Entity Framework, right click and update. This will ensure the code matches the database. Are you connecting the correct database?

Comment: I am using LINQ - SQL. I had to have a few statements to match the ID's of each and then I used the ".Find" method to get each record and populated a list of the agent type and then sent that list to the view. I know it feels like a loooong way to do it. For me right now it solved the problem so I guess for now im ok with that. but need to find a shorter solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help you guys. I actually had to change the name of my table too for some reason it was looking at the older name. I changed it from plural to singular and it dont know why ignored it for so long. Thanks kirk and @Eranga. ur suggestions did help a lot :)